# Life expectancy in the Gerry Anderson Universe?

Tags: gerry-anderson, fireball-xl5

[Steve Zodiac](https://gerryanderson.fandom.com/wiki/Steve_Zodiac) appears to have been born in 2030, making him in his mid 30's during the time that Fireball XL5 was set (2065).

However, I came across the following comment Steve made in a story from the 1966 TV21 Annual (see attachment): "Court-martial! Who cares - what's a few years in jail compared with **another ninety years** of life?".

Was the life expectancy in the Gerry Anderson universe typically 120 - 125 years? I don't recall any other instances where such an extended life span of a person was acknowledged. It is possible that, given the closeness 2065 to the present date and the reason for the increased lifespan that there mightn't actually be any people in their early-mid 100's present. Any feedback on the details of when and how this extension was achieved, or other examples where extended life-spans were mentioned?

[image]